# Exit button inside JQuery Mobile on WebView

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, webview

I'm trying to make an Android app with WebView and using JQuery Mobile inside. I wonder if the exit button would close the apps. What should I code ?

[Exit Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddQsg.jpg)

```html
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
   <div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#anylink" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="new_2.html" data-icon="edit">Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anylink" data-icon="action">Exit</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript code to show what you've tried?  This seems like you're asking us to do the work.  An initial attempt would show us what you understand, and how we can help you understand better.

Comment: I don't make it yet. Sorry I didn't mean like that. Well, my English isn't good well. So is it possible to JavaScript to make this apps goes exit? If JavaScript would be added to this, maybe you could give me references @incutonez

Answer (score 0):

You can close the app this way:

```
  <li><a onclick="navigator.app.exitApp();" data-icon="action">Exit</a></li>
```